# Burnination of D&D 4e power type tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

We have some old 4e tags that should probably be cleaned up:

- <s>[utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers)</s> (burninated)
- <s>[daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)</s> (burninated)
- <s>[encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)</s> (burninated)
- [sustained-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustained-powers) **(preserved at doppelgreener's request)**

These should be replaced with the more general [powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers) tag. This change is in a similar vein to the recent decision not to have tags for the 3.P schools of magic, and to instead use the [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) tag as well as possibly more thematic tags such as mind control, creating undead, etc. as needed by the community.

So far the following tags on these questions have been replaced with [powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers):

- [Is it possible to use Fey step to bypass locks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/is-it-possible-to-use-fey-step-to-bypass-locks) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers) (a recent question which brought the issue to light)
- [Do I have to prepare wizards level 2 encounter spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77132/do-i-have-to-prepare-wizards-level-2-encounter-spells) [utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Can a character with Ghost of the Rooftops climb like Spider-Man?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/can-a-character-with-ghost-of-the-rooftops-climb-like-spider-man) [utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers)
- [Responding to Opportunity Attacks with Snarling Wolf Stance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36792/responding-to-opportunity-attacks-with-snarling-wolf-stance) [utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers)
- [How does "Skilled Companion" work in Dungeons and Dragons 4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36746/how-does-skilled-companion-work-in-dungeons-and-dragons-4e) [utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers)
- [Does glowering threat work the same way as a mark or differently?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33403/does-glowering-threat-work-the-same-way-as-a-mark-or-differently) [utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers)
- [How often can secondary powers be used?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/how-often-can-secondary-powers-be-used) [utility-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility-powers) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Using an Encounter Power with Combat Challenge? [Martial Power II]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58497/using-an-encounter-power-with-combat-challenge-martial-power-ii) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [How exactly does Phrenic Strike Work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57111/how-exactly-does-phrenic-strike-work) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Why does Infernal Wrath's burst 10 target 1 enemy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/why-does-infernal-wraths-burst-10-target-1-enemy) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [How many Encounter Powers can I use during an Encounter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26404/how-many-encounter-powers-can-i-use-during-an-encounter) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Replacing Dilettante power with a level 13 encounter power](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/replacing-dilettante-power-with-a-level-13-encounter-power) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Does readying an encounter or daily power expend it automatically?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6528/does-readying-an-encounter-or-daily-power-expend-it-automatically) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Are the victims of Wrathful Aspect spared if they are immune to Fear?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10707/are-the-victims-of-wrathful-aspect-spared-if-they-are-immune-to-fear) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Does Bolt of Genius restore ALL of a Cleric's uses of Healing Word or just one?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/does-bolt-of-genius-restore-all-of-a-clerics-uses-of-healing-word-or-just-one) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Is a utility power that has the encounter keyword considered an "encounter power"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/is-a-utility-power-that-has-the-encounter-keyword-considered-an-encounter-power) [encounter-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-powers)
- [Is Reaper's Challenge really that broken? Did I get it wrong?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/is-reapers-challenge-really-that-broken-did-i-get-it-wrong) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Is there time after a free action triggers to use another free action before continuing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71044/is-there-time-after-a-free-action-triggers-to-use-another-free-action-before-con) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Warlock's Shadow Legion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62307/warlocks-shadow-legion) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Can the Pixie's Teleport Trick make you invincible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22679/can-the-pixies-teleport-trick-make-you-invincible) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Persistent Threat and Rain of Steel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26981/persistent-threat-and-rain-of-steel) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [Are Pathfinder daily spells 24hours or date](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15324/are-pathfinder-daily-spells-24hours-or-date) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [What's the duration of Savage Transformation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13786/whats-the-duration-of-savage-transformation) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)
- [How often per Day can the Living Missile Attack power be used?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/how-often-per-day-can-the-living-missile-attack-power-be-used) [daily-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-powers)

Comment: For large tag sets, we can use a mod-tool to rename them all at once, if it's decided to be done. (That avoids editing/bumping large numbers of Qs.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie None of these are large sets; at most a dozen questions.

Comment: Cool. It's still an *option* for small sets (it's not burdensome to use), but then it's a trade off between just doing it and waiting for a mod. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll probably knock them out in small bursts of 5-6 questions at a time, waiting for each burst to fall off the front page before doing another.

Comment: The [powers] tag itself is kind of awkward: it’s very 4e-centric. And on its face, it seems like a superset of [spells]. But nonetheless it still seems like the right tag to use.

Comment: @KRyan [there's a few other games that have powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers+-dnd-4e); D&D 4e uses the term because it's one of them (and is ~75% of its questions because of volume).

Comment: @doppelgreener Sure, but “power” isn’t the term used in a lot of games. E.g. Exalted and its charms, which are the same concept as 4e powers. Or 3.5e’s use of “power” to refer specifically to psionics.

Comment: @KRyan I don't disagree with any of that, I'm just not sure why it occurs as 4e-centric or as awkward. In those games that have a concept of powers, [powers] is the topic; D&D 4e is one of those and so uses it, and D&D 4e hasn't defined the [powers] tag AFAIK to the detriment of any other games that share the tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Are tags with no questions still deleted if they have a tag wiki entry? I just noticed the [encounter-powers] tag has one.

Comment: @ObliviousSage They're not deleted, but I'm not 100% sure what that implies. It's probably not worth worrying about in this case though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll keep an eye on the tag and if it's still around in a couple days without any questions then we can revisit the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would request you don't burninate [sustained-powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustained-powers). Leave it as-is.

The other tags are "a power, but with this timing or categorisation". That's not all that functionally important. I don't personally object to burninating those.

But sustained powers are a whole bag of mechanics on their own requiring unique understanding because of what's involved in a power being sustained. That's a distinct topic materially worth tagging and enabling people to search.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, but it's a reasonable enough position that I'm willing to leave the tag alone. We might want to do a search for questions that *should* have it but don't; I suspect we've gotten more than 6 questions about sustaining powers.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with that searching.

Comment: It occurs to me that we also might want to rename or synonymize the tag to allow it to be used more broadly; sustaining powers is thematically equivalent to concentration in other editions of D&D, and I'm sure if we go looking we can find similar mechanics in other games (keeping an effect active by devoting "effort" to it). On the other hand I could see that leading to confusion, so maybe not.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'd rather let D&D 4e tag them as sustained powers, D&D 5e tag it as concentration, and so on for other games rather than enforce a universal tag based on surface similarities. Merging them will probably be unhelpful, at the very least for being able to recognise the tags attached to a post for what they mean, and will cause trouble if we enforce "concentration is the tag for this concept" but that one game has both that concept (but not called concentration) *and* an entirely different mechanic called concentration.

Comment: I was just brainstorming in text form, so I'm not wedded to the idea. That seems like a pretty good counterargument.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I read it that way; no problem. I appreciate the opportunity to try to articulate something that had been sitting on my mind. :)

Comment: Can you drop [status-completed] on this question, since all the tags that we agreed to burninate are now deader than Hitler (who is in cryo-storage in Brazil)?

Comment: Sure thing, added :D